# Why find_by scope returns an array when the result is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a scope in my model:

```
scope :default_template, ->(template_type) { find_by(is_default: true, template_type: template_type) }
```

I'm using `find_by` but the problem is: when there is no record, the result of the scope is a blank array instead of `nil`.

```
EmailTemplate.default_template('blahblah')  # => []
```

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's stated in the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope):

> ... If it returns nil or false, an all scope is returned instead.

In order for your scope to be composable, it should return an ActiveRecord::Relationship, and if no record satisfies the given criteria an empty ActiveRecord::Relationship is returned. That ensures that further scope invocations in the model don't raise a NoMethodError when invoking them on a `nil` result.

If you really need it to return nil, then make your scope a class method. That will preserve the original return value.